# How can I fix the 'Import flaskr.db could not be resolved' error during Flask tutorial?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Conditions: macOS Monterey version 12.6.3, Editor: Visual Studio Code,
`(.venv) NameMacBook-Pro:flask-tutorial name$ pip list
Package            Version

---

blinker            1.6.2
click              8.1.3
Flask              2.3.2
importlib-metadata 6.6.0
itsdangerous       2.1.2
Jinja2             3.1.2
MarkupSafe         2.1.2
pip                21.2.4
setuptools         58.0.4
Werkzeug           2.3.4
zipp               3.15.0`

While following the flask tutorial(https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/), I experienced the error of "Import "flaskr.db" could not be resolved" in making auth.py in the step: Blueprints and Views (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/views/). I was able to see 'Hello World' in the step Application Setup (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/factory/). With the error in auth.py, I continued onto the step:Static Files and I performed flask run. The result in the terminal is as follows,
`(.venv) NameMacBook-Pro:flask-tutorial name$ flask run

- Serving Flask app 'flaskr'
- Debug mode: off
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
  Press CTRL+C to quit`

but the page just shows Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/login shows Internal Server Error.

I tried to flask run after performing export FLASK_APP=flaskr, which didn't resolve this error. I expect correctly reproduce the webpage the tutorial aims to make.

For reference, I provide shots about the folder structure and the point of error in the code(auth.py).

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O80sR.png)

[Point of error in auth.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq2aj.png)

Comment: please share the error

Comment: Please refer to the image Point of error in auth.py. Import "flaskr.db" could not be resolved is shown in from flaskr.db import get_db. In flask run, I don't receive an error but the url only shows not found on the server or Internal Server Error, which are different from the behavior in the tutorial. Please let me know if there are more things I should share as I am not familiar with coding and being just a beginner, I am not sure what to share. Thank you very much.

Comment: please share the error which appera in the terminal (where you are using flaskr run), when you hit the auth endpoint

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very similar to when I restarted my work another day and forgot to reactivate the new flask app. You can try the following without harming anything:

1. in whatever terminal you're using, navigate to the correct directory. In the flask tutorial, it's labeled `flask-tutorial`.
2. run your new flask app by inputting: `flask --app flaskr run --debug`

You may need to change `flask-tutorial` and/or `flaskr` to something else if you decided on a name that differs from the tutorial. If you're not sure, you can always navigate to where you created your project, look at what the folders are named, then compare it to the project layout as shown in the Flask tutorial project layout: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/layout/